# WCF Receber Resposta em UTF-8

Tags: c#, soap, wcf, utf-8, soapclient

Estou consumindo um `Webservice` de terceiros por meio de um *Console application*.

Recebo um objeto como retorno e, neste objeto preciso ler um atributo chamado `ReturnMessage`.

Porém o texto vem desconfigurado, o mesmo se apresenta da seguinte forma "**O CÃ³digo de SeguranÃ§a enviado Ã© InvÃ¡lido**.". Para corrigir o problema, criei um método que formata a string passada para *UTF-8*, segue o código abaixo.

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(texto);
 string textoFormatado = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);   
 return textoFormatado;
```

Após formatado a mensagem fica da seguinte forma "**O Código de Segurança enviado é Inválido**"

A minha pergunta é, não tem como eu já receber este retorno em *UTF-8* sem ter que ficar fazendo essa conversão?

Imaginei que poderia parametrizar algo no *app.config* como fiz abaixo, mas não funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia se isso é possível?

Comment: O que você fez está correto, você se assegurou de setar o `bindingConfiguration` como "BasicHttpBinding_IPagador" no endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso daqui:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(Message);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Referência:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h

Comment: O método que fiz está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que eu não queria fazer isso no código e sim definir essa configuração no web.config

Comment: Entendi... É só conheço essa forma. Abraço!